# ProcessBuilder doesn't recognize gcc command

Tags: java, gcc, processbuilder

I'm trying to run gcc via ProcessBuilder, but it says:
'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

But running gcc via cmd works.

Here is code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String command = "gcc C:\\Users\\pawel\\Desktop\\CFG-master\\test.c";
    System.out.println(executeCommand(command));
}

public static String executeCommand(String command) {
    String line;
    String result = "";
    try {
        ProcessBuilder builder;

        builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", command);
        builder.directory(new File("C:\\Users\\pawel"));
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            result += line + "\n";
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception = " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

[cmd screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE4ZF.png)

Comment: It's a little bit of guessing, but please check `System.getenv()` for `PATH`-like entries. Also, the windows command shell likes to inject an `.exe` extension, while I don't know about java, so try `String command = "gcc.exe ..."`, if that's the name of the executable.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "check System.getenv() for PATH-like entries"?

Comment: I meant to manually inspect them, e.g. by dumping to `System.out`. My point is, that java launches a shell from the environment the JVM was created with, so there might by differences to a shell you open on your desktop. For locating commands, Windows uses the `PATH` variable (case-insensitive), so I'd like to know, if any of the directories enlisted there contains an executable named `gcc.exe` or `gcc`.

Comment: There is no gcc or gcc.exe in System.getenv() output

Comment: I know, please check if **any of the directories enlisted** in a `PATH`-like entry contains such an executable. If that is what you did, we have indeed a difference between your JVM environment and your shell environment, so you need to fix that by adding the respective folder (containing `gcc`) to the `PATH` variable in your java program while configuring the ProcessBuilder through its `ProcessBuilder.environment()` method.

Comment: thanks, I was looking for this :)